# Match a string pattern multiple times in the same line

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find a specific pattern inside a string.

The pattern: `(\{\$.+\$\})`
Example matche: `{$ test $}`

The problem I have is when the text has 2 matches on the same line. It returns one match.  Example: `this is a {$ test $} content {$ another test $}`

This returns 1 match:  `{$ test $} content {$ another test $}`

It should returns 2 matches:
`{$ test $}` and `{$ another test $}`

Note: I'm using Javascript

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Problem is that your regex `(\{\$.+\$\})` is greedy in nature when you use `.+` that's why it matches longest match between `{$` and `}$`.

To fix the problem make your regex non-greedy:

```
(\{\$.+?\$\})
```

Or even better use negation regex:

```
(\{\$[^$]+\$\})
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nD7nP6/1)

Comment: Great!  Thank you
I'll accept this answer once the approval timer is done.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [global match flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
Also using a negative lookahead would ensure that you are not missing any matches or not hitting any false matches.

```
var s = "this is a {$ test $} content {$ another test $}";
var reg = /\{\$.*?(?!\{\$.*\$\}).*?\$\}/g;
console.log(s.match(reg));
```